# Ember implement list/details view

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to implement a parent/child kind of view as below. i.e. a list is shown initially & on-click of any of the items, I want to be taken to the details view (passing the specific id, making a AJAX request and rendering the child template with the details)

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('pending-items', function() {
        this.route('pending-items-details', {
            path: 'details/:itemId'
        });
    });
});
```

My question is do I have to follow specific hiearchy for the folders while creating routes/controllers/templates given the above requirement for pending-items' & 'pending-items-details'

Also how do I render the child template with the details once I have the AJAX response ?

Answer (score 1):

I like to do what you want to do in this way:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('pending-items', function() {
        this.route('details', {
            path: ':item_id'
        });
    });
});
```

using Ember-cli , you can do that, if you haven't created yet

- ember generate template pending-items
- ember generate template pending-items/details

this will generate for you this files in template folder

- /pending-items.hbs
- /pending-items/details.hbs

to render the template you only have to put the **{{outlet}}** helper into the parent template, example :

/peding-items.hbs

```
<h1>Content of the template</h1>
<div class= 'details'>
    {{outlet}}
</div>
```

/pending-items/details.hbs

```
<h3> Details of an item</h3>
<p>something here</p>
```

**now run and enter in the browser url put :** //localhost:4200/pending-items/1

Comment: Thanks a lot...While you have shown the child (details) to be added under/within the parent (items), my question is if there is any use case of keeping them at the same level physically (i.e. routes/templates/controllers, etc ) at the same level, but having the path as /items/details/123

Comment: Also in your example, you have given paths for the templates...Would the other things (any models, controllers, etc) should follow the same physical paths ?

Comment: Also while rendering the details views, I need to make  an AJAX request using the dynamic segment id as POST param and then want to render the response in the child/details view. So how can I handle that (rendering of child view based on response data)?

Comment: yes, you can change the path like you did, but i think is unnecesary because it make the url very long , 

            this.route('pending-items-details', {
                path: 'verylong/details/:item_id'
            })

to  acces to this like before the path will be like //localhost:4200/pending-items/verylong/details/123

Comment: The only things you can mapping as i know are the templates, ember render everything you have into the templates(like components and helpers), but maybe you wonder about behaviors for that you need the other things, like controlers, route, and component files.

Comment: to retrieve information with the data you do it via the controller, 

  `model: function(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('name_of_the_model', params.item_id);
  }`

but i like to do it via the route adding this lines

`setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.set('name_of_model', model);
  }`

the next thing you need to do is render the model values into the child template